# PHP Interactive shell starup

Tags: php

I tried starting PHP's interactive shell by executing the command "PHP -a" without the qutation marks but all I got is blank space.  What could be wrong?

I am using Windows

Comment: No readline enabled?

Comment: how do I check if readline is enabled?

Comment: With `php -m` or `ldd` or your package manager

Comment: no readline enbled, how do I enable in Windows?

Comment: You're going to need Google and/or a compiler.

Comment: @mario That dup you picked is exclusively Unix related and this guy is using Windows So it is not really a Dup

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, that would have been a neccessary context information right from the start. But it's not like we don't have a dozen other duplicates.

Comment: @mario Good point, I found one and Dup'd it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Windows, press Enter after your ending PHP tag and then hit Ctrl-Z to denote the end-of-file:

```
C:\>php -a

Interactive mode enabled

<?php
echo "Hello, world!";
?>
^Z
Hello, world!
```

It works I tried it

Comment: Riggs you're answer is helpful and probably the only correct answer, just wondering any work around with instant feedback without ctrl-z, because it takes me out the interactive shell? If no work around please let me know so I can check this as answer. Thanks.

Comment: I dont know of one, sorry

Comment: It's ok, thanks Riggs, you're answer is the correct answer.